# Why were monasteries built in obscure places around Ireland?

Tags: middle-ages, ireland, monastery

I remember reading that monks built many monasteries around very obscure parts of medieval Ireland. Does anyone know why? Is it because they didn't want many people to know/join about their order?

Comment: "I remember reading...." Where did you read this? Also, please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Just googling your title question gives [this explanation](https://www.askaboutireland.ie/learning-zone/primary-students/subjects/history/history-the-full-story/early-christian-ireland/monasteries/) at the top of the first page of search results.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) Suggest you check into the origin of the monastic movement and the original meaning of hermits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simply, because monks wanted to live a quiet life in spiritual reflection, and get on with their work. They felt this was best done in isolation.

[YourIrishCulture](https://www.yourirish.com/history/christianity/monasteries-in-ireland)

> Many monasteries had been strategically built in certain locations beside lakes, in forest woods or even on small islands. This would allow the resident monks to live a quiet life in spiritual reflection without getting caught up in everyday public life.

Comment: I also think this is not unique to Ireland. The Catherine Monastery in Egypt or the monasteries on Mt. Athos or on the Meteora rocks in Greece (just to name a few famous ones) are in rather remote places as well.

Comment: Asceticism played a part but many early religious sites were built next to pagan sites to control them. Monasteries were very important centres but when Henry VIII introduced protestantism that included the dissolution of the monasteries in Ireland. Without the scholars, wine makers, and other activities, these places were slowly abandoned so while they're in remote locations now, they were once political and cultural hubs with economic activity too.

Comment: Probably the grand champion of this kind of idea was the [monastery that they built in Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papar) before the Norse decided to settle there. I think most likely the monks were initially carried there in Norse ships.

Comment: Define remote: in the days before good roads, people travelled by boat. Places on islands and peninsulas were easier to reach than places inland.